# CTreeCtrl with arrows when expanded

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Is it possible to set CTreeCtrl styles to show arrows when expanded, like in this image, instead of the usual +/- signs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have [ComCtrl v6 in your manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview) to enable Visual Styles in your application, then call `SetWindowTheme(hWndMyTree, L"Explorer", NULL);`

To fully emulate Vista you should also set the TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER and TVS_EX_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS [extended styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tree-view-control-window-extended-styles).